Is this DAE system overdetermined given the number of boundary conditions and unknown constants?
Currently I am working on a DAE system contained in a research article.
I am confused with whether the following DAE system is overdetermined.
Here is the system (Eq.2.44 in this paper):
\begin{aligned}
    & \xi' = \cos \varphi, \\
    & \eta' = \sin \varphi, \\
    & \varphi''' + \frac{\varphi'^3}{2} = \beta \lambda, \\
    & \left( 0 < t < a \leq \frac{1}{2} \right).
\end{aligned}
The boundary conditions are:
\begin{aligned}
    & \xi(0) = 0, \\
    & \eta(0) = 0, \\
    & \varphi(0) = 0, \\
    & \varphi'(a) = 0, \\
    & \varphi''(0) = 0, \\
    & \xi(a) = 0, \\
    & \varphi(a) = \frac{\pi}{2}, \\
    & \int_0^a \xi \sin \varphi \, dt = \frac{A}{2}.
\end{aligned}
The total order of the ODE system is $5$, and we also need to find out $2$ unknown constants $a$ and $\beta$.
$\lambda$ and $A$ are given parameters. However, it seems that there are $8$ boundary conditions provided. I am not sure if all these boundary conditions are compatible with the system or if they make the problem overdetermined.
How should I approach checking the consistency and determining the correct number of boundary conditions for this system?

You need to determine whether one boundary condition can be deduced form the others or not.

In what way is this a DAE? It looks like any ODE system, especially if you make the integral into an extra component with $\psi'=\xi\sin\phi$, $\psi(0)=0$, $\psi(a)=A/2$. Then you get state dimension 6 functions + 2 constants, and 9 boundary conditions. This still does not match, but that defect does not make it into a DAE system.

@LutzLehmann Thanks for your insight. I referred to the system as a DAE system primarily because it doesn't include differential constraints on the variables $a$ and $\beta$. This may be inappropriate.

Yes, formally one can see that as an explicit index-1 system. But as the algebraic variables are constants, their derivative is zero, thus it is trivial to change to the fully ODE system. If the variable end-point is a problem, change the time parameter so that the new one is over $[0,1]$, then $a$ is a factor in the equations.
